# order of elements in a mapping space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, classifying-spaces

Let $B$ be a finite CW-complex and $\xi$ be a vector bundle over $B$ with structure group $\Sigma_n$, the $n$-th symmetric group.
Then corresponding to $\xi$, we have a classifying map
$$
g\in \tilde {KO}(B)\subseteq [B;B\Sigma_n].
$$

**Question:** does "B is a finite CW-complex" $\Longrightarrow$ "each element $g\in \tilde {KO}(B)$ has finite order"? Why?

Comment: This set of homotopy classes is not a group (as far as I know) so what do you mean by the order of an element?

Comment: Are you asking whether the image of the map $[B,B\Sigma_n]\to \widetilde{KO}^0(B)$ lies in the torsion subgroup? In general it is very *false* that $[B,B\Sigma_n]=\widetilde{KO}^0(B)$.